# How do I specify multiple javascript modal parameters with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal created using Twitter Bootstrap. I want to open using javascript. Right now I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="js">$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#my-modal").modal('show')
});
</script>
```

However, I want to include the backdrop and keyboard attributes as well. Twitter's documentation show the options as:

```
$('#my-modal').modal({
  keyboard: true
})

$('#my-modal').modal({
  backdrop: true
})
```

Using any combination of the three options does not work. I'm not very good with javascript so I don't know what's going on. I'm reading javascript tutorials right now to see where I went wrong, but so far no luck.

[Twitter Bootstrap's modal documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modal)

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Twitter Bootstrap, but from a quick glance at the reference you linked to it looks like `.modal()` method is taking an object to specify parameters so to specify multiple parameters you should be able to do this:

```
$('#my-modal').modal({
   show : true,
   keyboard : true,
   backdrop : true
});
```

The bit in the curly brackets `{}` is standard JavaScript object literal syntax, where you can specify multiple properties separated by commas.