# Unable to change options for Twitter Bootstrap modal WHILE visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My code:

```
modal.modal({keyboard: true, backdrop: true});
```

and

```
function submit(modal){
    modal.data('modal').options.keyboard = false;
    modal.data('modal').options.backdrop = 'static';
    /* Do other stuff */
};
```

However, after running function `submit`, clicking the backdrop or pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> causes the modal to hide. I know that the `modal` variable is correct, as running `modal.modal('hide');` works in function `submit`. The `submit` function script is being called **while** the modal is visible.

How can I change these options and have them take effect immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to use the following:

```
modal.off('keyup.dismiss.modal');
$('div.modal-backdrop').off();
```

The first disabled the escape key binding and the latter disabled the click event on the backdrop.

Comment: @FabioG I believe the namespaced events were changed in v3. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-events should be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of how you should use it.

```
$('#my-modal').modal({
show : true,
keyboard : true,
backdrop : true
});
```

You can also find this question answered here: [How do I specify multiple javascript modal parameters with Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937467/how-do-i-specify-multiple-javascript-modal-parameters-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to change options _while_ the modal is open, not when I initialize it. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/DCR4Y/19/.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply add this:

```
 data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
```

to the modal itself:

```
 <a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" href="#myModal" >Launch Modal</a>
```

Then use JavaScript to change this when modal opens. That should help you customize the modal as needed.

Comment: This doesn't change the settings while the modal is open, which is what I need.